# Can I raise a signal from python?

Tags: python, signals, ipc

The topic basically tells what I want to to.

I read the documentation, which tells me how to handle signals but not how I can do signalling by myself.

Thanks!

Comment: please clarify: Are you talking about signals on a OS-level or about signals as in Qt, the concepts of signals and slots.

Comment: please clarify: Are you talking about signals on a OS-level or about signals as in turning signals, the concept of indicating left or right turning

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the `os.kill` method. Since Python 2.7 it should work (did not test it myself) on both Unix and Windows, although it needs to be called with different parameters:

```
import os, signal

os.kill(pid, signal.SIGHUP) # Unix version only...
```

Answer (score 30):

Use [`os.kill`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.kill). For example, to send `SIGUSR1` to your own process, use

```
import os,signal
os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGUSR1)
```

Answer (score 12):

Directly with the `signal` package (*new in version 3.8*). For instance:

```
import signal
signal.raise_signal( signal.SIGINT )
```

---

Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#signal.raise_signal

Answer (score 3):

Just proposing a different method, if its on windows:

```
import ctypes
ucrtbase = ctypes.CDLL('ucrtbase')
c_raise = ucrtbase['raise']
c_raise(some_signal)
```

`some_signal` can be any signal num, eg `signal.SIGINT`.

Comment: this worked well to stop Flask cleanly from within a request. `os.kill` just stopped it instantly which wasn't what I was after